# How/Where to find such special symbol/character?

Tags: symbols, characters, extended-characters

I am developing a mobile app. In this app, I need some special characters and symbols, e.g. `θ, ʒ, ʃ, dʒ, t͡ʃ` I have found all I need except one symbol.

How can I write (or where can I find) a letter like that:

[image]

And also I want to know what is the best way of searching such symbols. What are they called?

Note: The symbol I look for is not single character.
    I might be able to use it as I use ^ symbol (like â, ê).
    What I mean is singleton symbol does not work in my case.
    The symbol should be secondary symbol along with the letter.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I guess you need `tipa`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate little bit?

Answer (score 6):

Those symbols are in IPA:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}

\begin{document}

\textsubbridge{t}\quad
\textyogh\quad
\textesh\quad
\textdyoghlig\quad
\textteshlig

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the last one you might prefer

```
\texttoptiebar{t\textesh}
```

[image]

The characters are available in some OpenType fonts, for example FreeSerif. Compile the following with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}

\begin{document}

\textsubbridge{t}\quad
\textyogh\quad
\textesh\quad
\textdyoghlig\quad
\textteshlig\quad
\texttoptiebar{t\textesh}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I need it as character not image file. Is there any way for that?

Comment: @JustWork The example code produces the shown output.

Answer (score 1):

Build your own.  The parameters `\rlwd` and `\rldp` can be changed, as well as the 1pt underset gap.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc,stackengine}
\def\rlwd{.5pt}
\def\rldp{.3ex}
\def\underframe#1{\stackunder[1pt]{#1}{\rule[-\rldp]{\rlwd}{\rldp}\kern-\rlwd%
  \rule{\widthof{#1}}{\rlwd}\kern-\rlwd\rule[-\rldp]{\rlwd}{\rldp}}}
\begin{document}
This is a \underframe{t} and \underframe{A}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here it is with `\def\rlwd{.3pt}` and `\def\rldp{.4ex}`:

[image]

If you found the underframe too wide, you could replace in the definition `{\widthof{#1}}` with `{\widthof{#1}-1pt}`, for example, obtaining something that doesn't overhang the serifs.

[image]